# Convert strings with periods to uppercase - Python

Tags: python, string, uppercase, data-wrangling

I am trying to convert a series of markets to uppercase so I can match with a zip dictionary. When I loop through the string and convert to uppercase, it works fine, as so:

```
def uppercase(series):
    for string in series:
        print(string.upper())
    
uppercase(markets.County)
```

But when I try to append this to a new list or with list comprehension, it fails:

```
def uppercase(series):

    string_upper = []
    
    for string in series:
        string_upper.append(string.upper())
    
uppercase(markets.County)
```

With an attribute error that it can't convert the periods to uppercase. But it just did that in the code above.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2c8a689b8491> in <module>
      6         string_upper.append(string.upper())
      7 
----> 8 uppercase(markets.County)

<ipython-input-25-2c8a689b8491> in uppercase(series)
      4 
      5     for string in series:
----> 6         string_upper.append(string.upper())
      7 
      8 uppercase(markets.County)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

This seems like a 2 second simple solution. Why is it failing when it has to append the new data?

Comment: string_upper.append(string)

Comment: The error is clear enough. in your series, you have object(s) which are not a string. you should check before using `.upper()` method. use a try/except block to find the problem or simply just convert to upper when the object is a string.

Comment: If you add `print(type(string))` in between lines 5 (`for string in series:`) and 6 (the one that changes), what does it output in each case?

Answer (score 1):

When printing a variable to `stdout` there are implicit conversions of variables to string representation. So, in fact, what is happening is:

1. Variable is converted to string (equivalent to `str(var)` if `var` is the variable)
2. The converted value is written to `stdout`

This means that you need to perform additional checks (if you wish to omit non-string values) or conversions (if you wish to perform explicit conversion of each value that is not string).

So you need to amend your code to do just that:

```
def uppercase(series):

    string_upper = []
    
    for value in series:
        string_upper.append(str(value).upper())
```